# Using @:arrayAccess, but still "Array access not allowed"

Tags: haxe

I have written the following (very simple) ring buffer class, which should allow array access via the **@:arrayAccess** macro:

```
class RingBuffer<T>
{
    private var _elements : Array<T> = null;

    public function new(p_numElements : Int, p_defaultValue : T)
    {
        _elements = new Array<T>();

        for (i in 0 ... p_numElements)
        {
            _elements.push(p_defaultValue);
        }
    }

    public function add(p_value : T) : Void
    {
        // Remove the first element
        _elements.splice(0, 1);
        _elements.push(p_value);
    }


    @:arrayAccess public inline function get(p_index : Int)
    {
      return _elements[p_index];
    }

    @:arrayAccess public inline function set(p_index : Int, p_value : T)
    {
        _elements[p_index] = p_value;
        return p_value;
    }
}
```

But when I try to use array access on an instance of the class, I get an error telling me **"Array access is not allowed on..."**.

Did I do something wrong in using the macro? I was basically following the example [in the manual](http://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-array-access.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@:arrayAccess` is only allowed on abstracts (not classes), which is why it's in the [Abstracts section of the Haxe manual](http://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-array-access.html). That page you linked also states:

> Nevertheless, with **abstracts** it is possible to define custom array access methods.

What you could do is rename your class to `RingBufferImpl` and create an `abstract` named `RingBuffer` to wrap that type and provide array access:

```
@:forward
@:access(RingBufferImpl)
abstract RingBuffer<T>(RingBufferImpl<T>) from RingBufferImpl<T>
{
    @:arrayAccess public inline function get(p_index : Int)
    {
      return this._elements[p_index];
    }

    @:arrayAccess public inline function set(p_index : Int, p_value : T)
    {
        this._elements[p_index] = p_value;
        return p_value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var buffer:RingBuffer<Int> = new RingBufferImpl<Int>(10, 0);
buffer[0] = 5;
for (i in 0...10)
    trace(buffer[i]);
```

Note that `@:arrayAcess` is not a macro, but [metadata](http://haxe.org/manual/lf-metadata.html) - specifically [built-in compiler metadata](http://haxe.org/manual/cr-metadata.html), as indicated by the `:`.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clearing that up. I got to the metadata just by googling, thus not paying much attention to where exactly it was in the manual.  
That is all a bit of a hassle to write, of course - wish there was a better way, like actual operator overloading. But at least the user of the class won't have to see it all ;)

Comment: I noticed an error when using your code: "Cannot access private field _elements" inside the arrayAccess function.

Comment: That's why my example has `@:access(RingBufferImpl)`, to be able to access the private fields of `RingBufferImpl`. If you copied my code 1:1, and your ring buffer is in some subpackage, that needs to be updated: `@:acess(path.to.RingBufferImpl)`